# How to get the total number of comment of a channel using YouTube Data API

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using YouTube Data API and can get subscriber count, view count etc. by using the `statistics` parameter. I am aware that `statistics` cannot be used to get total likeCount and commentCount for a channel. But the API allows to get the playlist videos using `contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads`.

So, my question is

How can I use the `contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads` to fetch individual videos' likes and comments and append them into a JS variable?

**EDIT**

The embedded videos with titles are showing perfectly. But `commentCount` for the video does not show up.
Here is the code

```
function requestVideoPlaylist(playlistId) {
  const requestOptions = {
    playlistId: playlistId,
    part: 'snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
    maxResults: 10
  };

  const request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list(requestOptions);

  request.execute(response => {
    console.log(response);
    const playListItems = response.result.items;
    if (playListItems) {
      let output = '<br><h4 class="center-align">Latest Videos</h4>';

      // Loop through videos and append output
      playListItems.forEach(item => {
          const videoId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
          const videoTitle = item.snippet.title;
          const videoComment = item.statistics.commentCount;

        output += `
          <div class="col s3">
          <iframe width="100%" height="auto" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
"${videoTitle}" "${videoComment}"
          </div>
        `;
      });

      // Output videos
      videoContainer.innerHTML = output;
    } else {
      videoContainer.innerHTML = 'No Uploaded Videos';
    }
  });
}
```

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I personally use URL endpoints with `statistics` in `part` of [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) and it works fine.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison A code sample would be greatly appreciated. If you can post an answer with code sample, I can approve that as answer if that works. I am using foreach for the `response.result.items` and getting the video id and title as follows `const videoId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId; const videoTitle = item.snippet.title;`. How can I use the `Videos list` filter? I will appreciate your response.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison I have tried with `statistics` in `part`. Here is what I did `part: 'snippet,contentDetails,statistics'`. Then used `item.statistics.commentCount;`. But that returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the `commentNumber` from the `statistics` `part` of [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) in plain JavaScript (because what you seem to do with the library seems correct but not working):

```
var getJSON = function(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var status = xhr.status;
      if (status === 200) {
        callback(null, xhr.response);
      } else {
        callback(status, xhr.response);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
};

getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=VIDEO_ID&key=API_KEY',
function(err, data) {
  if (err !== null) {
    alert('Something went wrong: ' + err);
  } else {
    alert('The video commentCount: ' + data.items[0].statistics.commentCount);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I am not doing it thru JSON. Please check my EDITED question to find out. Call is made using `gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list`. What am I doing wrong? Why is the commentCount not showing up? Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: A quick question. If I do it the way you showed, would YouTube deduct 1 unit for each video? I need to retrieve 10 latest videos of a channel, and 1 unit per video will badly impact my quota limit. The way I am doing it right now requires only 1 unit for the entire call(10 videos or more). Please keep me posted. Thanks

Comment: 1. "because what you seem to do with the library seems correct but not working" so I can't help you much more with their library. 2.  you can request up to 50 videos data with the Videos: list endpoint for a quota of 1 (not 1 per video except if you request the video one by one). For requesting 50 videos at once, you have to use id=VIDEO_ID_0,VIDEO_ID_1,...,VIDEO_ID_49